# Soap: How to validate empty elements

Tags: java, soap, jaxb, jax-ws, cxf

How is it possible to validate that an element in a Soap-Request must exist and must contain a value?
I have a webservice that receives Soap requests which contain mandatory-values. These values must not be empty and must exist in the xml-document.

If I use

```
@XmlElement(nillable=false, required=true)
```

to achieve that, I can validate that the element must exist and that it may not be empty if the element has the attribute

```
xsi:nil="true"
```

But what if the client does not add the nil-attribute and just send an empty element like

```
<element/>
```

How can I define that this is forbidden? In other words: How can I define that only elements like

```
<element>value</element>
```

are allowed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[JAXB facets](http://www.infosys.tuwien.ac.at/staff/hummer/tools/jaxb-facets.html) claims to that

> the generated WSDL file describing the service interface will contain
>   an XSD declaration

that was defined with annotations.
If you're using code first approach, you could generate WSDL and deploy your WS, instead of leaving WSLD generation for JAX-WS runtime.

Comment: I'm using code-first approach. The wsdl is generated from the ServiceImplementation. I dont want to edit the wsdl manually after it has been generated. So I need a way to define that a field may not be empty by annotations or something else that infuences the generation-process.